# How can Android Mediaplayer open a videostream using an SDP file

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mediaplayer, rtp

I want to use Android mediaplayer to open a video over a RTP stream I create with gstreamer.

I put the stream information in an SDP-file and try to load it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback{

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    Log.d("App", "Mediaplayer starting");
    mediaPlayer.start();
    Log.d("App", "MP Playing");
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);


    // I tried this also and failed
    //Uri uri = Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/mjpg.sdp");

    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/mjpg.sdp");
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/sdcard/victamjpg.sdp");
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("App", e.getMessage());
    }
    Log.d("App", "Player created");
}
```

This produces the errors

> 10-29 22:11:09.510 2781-2781/? D/App: setDataSource failed.
>
> 10-29 22:11:09.510 2781-2781/? D/App: Player created

And `onPrepared` is never executed

This is how the stream is sent.

`gst-launch-1.0 -v ximagesrc use-damage=false ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=320,height=200,framerate=25/1 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5200`

It works fine to receive with another instance of Gstreamer.

This is the content of the SDP-file

```
v=0
m=video 5002 RTP/AVP 92
c=IN IP4 10.0.2.2
a=rtpmap:96 JPEG/90000
```

From [this source](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) the 10.0.2.2 is pointing to the host machines loopback device.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @IvánPérez The problem was solved by compiling Gstreamer for Android and playing the stream using that player. I think the solution I tried with the native video player is a dead end. If you find out otherwise I'm interested in hearing the details.